# I am unable to get the output of Python program in VS Code it is on printing the path but not running the code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

If I want to run the code of Python in VS Code terminal I am not getting the output. I tried code runner or setting environmental variables, nothing works. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you run `python` without `-u`?

Comment: Have you tried using the play button on top right instead of manual command? Does it run then?

Answer (score 1):

- In your case, needed to save the file first; as in the picture, it is visible that the file is not saved.
  Press `cntrl+s`
- To use VScode, you need to open a folder. I suppose you directly opened the VScode and wrote a program. creates a folder in your machine and opened that
  folder/python.py then.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone who answered my question. my problem was solved when i added a new folder to vs code then the program started exexuting
once again thank you everyone
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB8Lx.png)